# Difficulty displaying\filtering products according to selected category in Flutter app with Firestore

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing a Flutter application that fetches products from Firestore and displays them based on the selected category. I have implemented functionality to select categories and filter products accordingly, but I'm encountering an issue where the product grid does not update to display products based on the selected category.

Here's a simplified overview of my code structure:

1. I have a CategoryList widget that fetches categories from Firestore
   and displays them horizontally. When a category is tapped, it
   triggers a callback (onCategorySelected) with the category ID. In
   the ProductGrid widget, I receive the selectedCategory ID as a
   parameter.
2. I use this ID to filter products from Firestore based on the
   selected category. The ProductsPage widget contains the CategoryList
   and ProductGrid widgets. It manages the selected category state and
   passes the selectedCategory ID to the ProductGrid widget when a
   category is selected.
3. Despite implementing these functionalities, when I tap on a category
   in the CategoryList, the product grid does not update to display
   products according to the selected category. so basically when i tap
   on a category products related to that category should be displayed

Before the code here is how my firebase has been arranged

i have a users collection
inside the users collection I have documents which are basically users
inside each user i have user details and 2 more documents products and categories(more to be added later)
inside categories we have the categories that the user will add
and inside the products collection we have products
each product has details such as basic infon such as name, quantity and most Important **selectedCategory** in this category the id of category is saved
which is similar to the id of a category in categories document
for example
if a category Mobiles is added the document Id that firestore stores assigns to it is saved inside the selectedcategory

Here's a snippet of my code:

here are two widgets one for category list
the other PRODUCTGRID shows products in grid view

```
class CategoryList extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String) onCategorySelected;
  const CategoryList({
    Key? key,
    required this.onCategorySelected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoryList> createState() => _CategoryListState();
}

class _CategoryListState extends State<CategoryList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .collection('categories')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Category> categories = snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((doc) => Category.fromSnapshot(doc))
              .toList();
          return SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: categories.length + 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  return _buildCategoryWidget(Icons.add, 'Add', () {
                    _showAddCategoryBottomSheet(context);
                  });
                } else if (index == 1) {
                  return _buildCategoryWidget(Icons.image, 'All', () {
                    widget.onCategorySelected('');
                    print('onTap Called');
                  });
                } else {
                  Category category = categories[index - 2];
                  return _buildCategoryWidget(Icons.image, category.title, () {
                    widget.onCategorySelected(category.categoryID);
                    print('onTap Called');
                    setState(() {});
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCategoryWidget(
      IconData iconData, String title, VoidCallback onTap) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 35,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Icon(iconData),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Text(title),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showAddCategoryBottomSheet(BuildContext context) async {
    File? selectedImage;

    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();

    Future<void> pickImage() async {
      final picker = ImagePicker();
      final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        setState(() {
          selectedImage = File(pickedImage.path);
        });
      }
    }

    // Function to handle image selection from camera

    if (user != null) {
      await showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        barrierColor: primaryBlue.withOpacity(0.3),
        builder: (context) {
          return BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Add Category',
                    style: customTextblack.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                    ),
                    width: size.width * 0.8,
                    height: size.height * 0.25,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        pickImage();
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          selectedImage != null
                              ? Image.file(
                                  selectedImage!,
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                )
                              : Icon(Icons.image),
                          Text('Upload An Image'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: titleController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Category Title'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  BottomSheetButton(
                      btntxt: 'Add',
                      onPressed: () async {
                        DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef =
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('users')
                                .doc(user.uid)
                                .collection('categories')
                                .doc();

                        await docRef.set({
                          'title': titleController.text,
                          'categoryID': docRef.id,
                          'Date Added': DateTime.now(),
                        });
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      width: size.width * 0.7,
                      height: size.height * 0.05)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
/////THIS CLASS FETCHES VALUES FROM categories document in firestore
class Category {
  final String title;
  final String categoryID;

  Category(this.title, this.categoryID);

  Category.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : title = snapshot['title'],
        categoryID = snapshot['categoryID'];
}

///////////////////////////////
////
/////PRODUCT GRIDS//////////
///////////////////
class ProductGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selectedCategory; // Selected category

  const ProductGrid({Key? key, required this.selectedCategory})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductGrid> createState() => _ProductGridState();
}

class _ProductGridState extends State<ProductGrid> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> productsList = [];
  String productTitle = '';
  String productQuantity = '';
  String productPrice = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchProductDetails();
  }

  void fetchProductDetails() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot;
      if (widget.selectedCategory.isNotEmpty) {
        snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('products')
            .where('selectedCategory', isEqualTo: widget.selectedCategory)
            .get();
      } else {
        snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('products')
            .get();
      }

      if (snapshot.size > 0) {
        setState(() {
          productsList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
        });
        // Note: The following lines may need adjustment based on your data structure
        Map<String, dynamic> productData = snapshot.docs[0].data();
        productTitle = productData['title'];
        productPrice = productData['price'];
        productQuantity = productData['quantity'];
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 0.88,
              mainAxisSpacing: size.height * 0.01,
              crossAxisSpacing: size.width * 0.017),
          itemCount: productsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Map<String, dynamic> productData = productsList[index];
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
                      // height: size.height * 0.18,
                      // width: size.width * 0.5,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ProductDetails()));
                            },
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/iphoneImage.png',
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: size.height * 0.015,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            productData['title'],
                            style: customTextblack,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            ('' + productData['quantity'] + ''),
                            style: customTextblack,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.2),
                      child: Text(productData['price'],
                          style: customTextgreen.copyWith(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.030,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

this my page where all these widgets are called and displayed

```
class ProductsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductsPage> createState() => _ProductsPageState();
}

class _ProductsPageState extends State<ProductsPage> {
  bool _categoriesLoaded = false; // Flag to track if categories are loaded
  bool _showAddProduct =
      false; // Flag to track if Add Product button should be shown
  String _selectedCategory = ''; // Track the selected category

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkCategories(); // Check if categories exist for the user
  }

  void _checkCategories() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      QuerySnapshot categoriesSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection('categories')
          .get();
      setState(() {
        _categoriesLoaded = true;
        _showAddProduct = categoriesSnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(75),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: size.width * 0.011,
            left: 12,
            right: 12,
          ),
          child: appBar(
            title: 'Products',
            addIcon: true,
            onPressedFunction: () {
              if (_showAddProduct) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddProduct()),
                );
              } else {
                _showAddCategoryDialog(context);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.051),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const AppSearchBar(
              hintText: 'Search Products',
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 22),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Opacity(
                    opacity: 0.4,
                    child: Text(
                      'Category',
                      style: customTextblack.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CategoriesScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'See All',
                      style: customTextblue.copyWith(
                        fontSize: size.width * 0.038,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        color: primaryBlue,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            CategoryList(
              onCategorySelected: (category) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedCategory = category;
                });
              },
            ),
            if (!_showAddProduct &&
                _categoriesLoaded) // Show message if no categories and categories are loaded
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                child: Text(
                  'Please add a category first',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            if (_showAddProduct) // Show product grid if categories exist
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: size.width * 0.63,
                  bottom: 4,
                ),
                child: Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.4,
                  child: Text(
                    'Products',
                    style: customTextblack.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            if (_showAddProduct)
              ProductGrid(
                  selectedCategory:
                      _selectedCategory), 
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showAddCategoryDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('No Categories Found'),
          content: Text('Please add a category first to add products.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Add Category'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```